# how to create json array of objects from php array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am having a php array containing some integer numbers as below

```
Array
(
    [0] => 41
    [1] => 64
    [2] => 51
    [3] => 42
    [4] => 65
    [5] => 52
    [6] => 66
    [7] => 67
)
```

Now i want to create json array of object like this.

```
[{"assosiated_id": 41}, {"assosiated_id": 42}, {"assosiated_id": 51}, {"assosiated_id": 52}, {"assosiated_id": 64}, {"assosiated_id": 65}, {"assosiated_id": 66}, {"assosiated_id": 67}]
```

I have tried converting this array into assosiative array then encode to json but assosiative array can not have duplicate values.please tell which is the best way to do it?

Comment: `json_encode([['associated_id' => 41], ['associated_id' => 42], /* ... */]);`?

Comment: I can't hard code it like you did.

Comment: Then "soft-code" it: `echo json_encode(array_map(function ($value) { return ['associated_id' => $value]; }, $myArray));`

Comment: I don't know why someone down vote it??

Comment: Because it's really not a hard question which you could've answered yourself with a tiny bit of research.

Comment: i am just beginner in php so i could not figure out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$a = [41, 64, 51, 42, 65, 52, 66, 67];
sort($a);
$b = [];
foreach ($a as $v) { 
    $b[] = ['associated_id' => $v]; 
}
echo json_encode($b);
```

gives

```
[{"associated_id":41},{"associated_id":64},{"associated_id":51}, {"associated_id":42},{"associated_id":65},{"associated_id":52},{"associated_id":66},{"associated_id":67}]
```

Alternatively you can just use the [Mark Baker's oneliner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937440/how-to-create-json-array-of-objects-from-php-array-in-php/30937641#comment49909988_30937440) in your comments

If you are using an older version of PHP you may have to code it like this

```
$a = array(41, 64, 51, 42, 65, 52, 66, 67);
sort($a);
$b = array();
foreach ($a as $v) { 
    $b[] = array('associated_id' => $v); 
}
echo json_encode($b);
```

Comment: If you're getting an `unexpected '['` error, then the chances are that you're running PHP an older version of PHP (< 5.4.0)

Comment: Hope you dont mind my adding the old array mechanism version

Comment: Absolutely not. I've picked up the new syntax right away when I started with PHP :)

Comment: You would be surprised how many sites are using PHP well below 5.4. Or maybe you wouldn't be.

Comment: I am running php 5.3 @MarkBaker

Comment: @deepakkumar Then use the alternate syntax using `array()` rather than `[]`

Answer (score 1):

please, change your array accordingly to php syntax, if this is what you meant

https://eval.in/384328

```
<?php
$data = Array
(
    0 => 41,
    1 => 64,
    2 => 51,
    3 => 42,
    4 => 65,
    5 => 52,
    6 => 66,
    7 => 67
);

$mapFunc = function($n) {
  return array('assosiated_id' => $n);
};

echo json_encode(array_map($mapFunc, $data));
```

Comment: Best solution if using php <5.4

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
<?php
$array = array(41,52,64,67,68,89,34);

$new = [];
foreach($array as $a)
{
    $b = array('assosiated_id' => $a);
    $new[] =$b;
}

echo json_encode($new);
```

output will be

```
[
{
assosiated_id: 41
},
{
assosiated_id: 52
},
{
assosiated_id: 64
},
{
assosiated_id: 67
},
{
assosiated_id: 68
},
{
assosiated_id: 89
},
{
assosiated_id: 34
}
]
```